# Creating files [loop] bash

Tags: bash, for-loop

A part of my task is to create files using for.. in.. do.. done loop

> `prwx, prw-, pr-x, pr--,p-wx, p-w-, p--x, p---`

How to change counter in loop?

Comment: What are those strings `prwx` etc?

Comment: And googling "bash for loop" didn't return anything you could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop or an individual list:

```
touch p{-,r}{-,w}{-,x}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for loop to create those strange file names:

```
for i in 'prwx' 'prw-' 'pr-x' 'pr--' 'p-wx' 'p-w-' 'p--x' 'p---'
do
   touch "./$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop.

```
touch prwx prw- pr-x pr-- p-wx p-w- p--x p---
```